# unit testing functions with callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, callback, karma-jasmine

I am new to angularJS and trying to unit test the function.
The plot is as follows:

controller.js

```
angular
    .module('portal')
    .controller('loginController', loginController);

loginController.$inject = ['$location','dataService'];
function loginController($location,dataService) {
    var loginControllerVm = this;

    loginControllerVm.login = login;
    function login() {
        loginControllerVm.dataLoading = true;
        console.log('coming here');
        dataService.authenticateUser(loginControllerVm.username, loginControllerVm.password,function (response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response.success)
            {

                $location.path('/profile');
            }
            else
            {
                 console.log('coming in login while testing');
                loginControllerVm.dataLoading = false;
                $location.path('/');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now in the login function we are call dataService authencticateUser function and the callback is just a boolean value

dataService is a service which acts as a middle layer between other services and controller.

I am not making an http call in the dataService the callback is just to convey that it executed.

callback({success:true});

and based on this I execute the if condition.

I want to unit test this login() function. I have started writting the test

test.js

```
 describe('loginController', function() {

//Inject 'app' module into this spec.
beforeEach(module('portal'));

var $q, $controller, injector, $scope,location;
var dataServiceMock = function(){
    return {
         authenticateUser: jasmine.createSpy()
    }
};

beforeEach(function(){
    inject(function(_$q_, _$injector_, _$controller_, _$rootScope_,$location){

        $q = _$q_;
        injector = _$injector_;
        location = $location;
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();

        dataServiceMock = injector.get('dataService');

    });
  controller = $controller('loginController', {$scope : $scope, dataService: dataServiceMock});
});
 it('successfully gets the list of items from the service', function() {
        spyOn(dataServiceMock, 'authenticateUser');

        spyOn(location, 'path');
        controller.login(); 
        expect(dataServiceMock.authenticateUser).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
});
```

The test is passing but when I look at the code coverage I get that the callback is not tested. So how should I go about testing that.

Also I would like to access the response variable and compare its values??

Any help would be appreciated...
Thanks

Comment: Thank you I have resolved it and leant it. You can refer this link http://plnkr.co/edit/6xdVwJsJba8SVZ6d6lgg?p=preview